Passport front page issues
My indian passport first laminated page seems to be opening on the corners where the machine readable code is located. What should i do?

Why don't you just apply for replacement/renewal ?

@Hilmar time+cost if it not useful to replace it (but yes it is useful to replace it).

@FranckDernoncourt Indian passport renewal is cheap, if its done in India. Its much better than to deal with stress of some overzealous airline agent or border agents messing with my travel plans.

The threshold for the passport to be considered 'damaged' is really low for Indian immigration. The damage you describe is definitely damage. You need to renew the passport for a smooth immigration.
PS: For some weird reason, they always ask about my previous passport being damaged every time I cross the border.

"they always ask about my previous passport being damaged every time I cross the border." what do they ask?

Agent: "Your previous passport was damaged, right? What happened?" Me: "Water damage, rain.". Agent: "OK". Rinse and repeat almost anytime when I enter/leave India. I don't know what they are trying to know. May be making smalltalk.
